# Why do you have to pay to get the Ubuntu One for windows?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I just noticed that ubuntu one is available for Windows if you subscribe.

https://one.ubuntu.com/plans/

Why is it limited?

It would be great advertising, and help the migration.

Comment: Canonical would probably like to make revenue from machines that use their data services but someone else's operating system as is certainly their right. Whether it makes economic sense is a good question, but essentially unanswerable, probably even to them given how new the service is.

Comment: Write to Canonical if you like, but I imagine voting with your wallet, as they say, would be more sincere.

Comment: I have voted to close the question as off-topic. It's impossible to answer by the community. Only Canonical itself can answer or comment their commercial politics.

Comment: @Javier Rivera:  I was hoping that someone in the community had already seen an answer to the question.

Comment: Comments on a question are not the best place to discuss scope of questions. You can voice your opinion with the vote to close - please use the [Ubuntu StackExchange Meta](http://meta.ubuntu.stackexchange.com) for discussion of question scope and other aspects of the site directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Windows client referred to on the plans page is for syncing contacts. We charge for this because the client is part of mobile sync and mobile sync costs some money to provide due to licensing fees Canonical pays for some of the server technology.

We are currently working on a Windows client for Ubuntu One that will allow you to sync files. It's not quite ready for public testing, but once it is, we'll announce it on our blog: http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone

Comment: Thanks for poking your head in here. This boosted my already extremely high appreciation of Canonical (which is a little hard to take to the bank, but still... ;)